# php 5.2.12 Maximum execution time when using include()

Tags: php

Anyone got a problem with php 5.2.12 getting a lot of " Maximum execution time()" error when trying to include files?

I can't seem to find the bug in php.net, but it's consistently giving us that error on numerous scripts.

Anyone can recommend solutions?

Comment: Are all the scripts including the same file(s)? What's in the file(s) you're including? You could do some profiling with http://xdebug.org/ and see what shows up in there.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the file that you are including is running some functions or codes that are taking time.

Include function it self do not take time. Instead its inside the file that you are including.

I would suggest you to check that first.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the max_execution_time variable in php.ini?  That is the maximum amount of time a script can run.  I don't know if there are any settings specifically for includes.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an IO problem when trying to get the file? Is the file local or on a NAS? Try including the file in a script by itself to make sure your not hitting a bug in your code somewhere else.